# Use multiple mongo DBs in same application for same model & same Repository

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I need to implement Spring boot - MongoDb application where There are 2 mongo DBs which have exact same database name & collections. Based on User making a request, i need to choose whether to fetch data from DB1 or DB2 (only difference in mongo URI host - IP).

E.g. I need some way to create 2 mongoTemplates like mTempA & mTempB in my Repository & based on some condition, use either of the template to execute query as below:

```
@Repository
public class MyCustomRepository {

private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCustomRepository.class);

@Autowired
private MongoTemplateA mongoTemplateA;// Need to know if this is possible & how

@Autowired
private MongoTemplateB mongoTemplateB;// Need to know if this is possible & how

public List<MyModel> findByCriteria(MyRequest request) {
    List<MyModel> result;
    //Query query = <build query based on request>

    if (request.getUserType().equals("A")) {
        result = mongoTemplateA.find(query, MyModel.class);
    } else {
        result = mongoTemplateB.find(query, MyModel.class);
    }

    logger.debug("Result fetched with {} records", result.size());
    return result;
}   
}
```

I don't want to have 2 separate Repo (Class or Interfaces) or different models to be used. Just want to have 2 different mongoTemplates to be injected in single repo.

Is this possible? If yes, please give some example code.
I have followed below tutorial:
https://dzone.com/articles/multiple-mongodb-connectors-with-spring-boot

Comment: I believe there are two ways to do that, one is that you already shown, that is to use your own repositoy class and implementing all the CRUD methods you need using your logic for  templates to use.
The second way is to use, aspects and then catching all the methods of the repository using @Before and then changing the mongoTemplateRef depending on your logic.

Comment: @Lucia The way I have shown is something I want but not implemented. Need to know how to initialise 2 templates in 1 repository with different sources. Either for this or the way you mentioned, can you please help with any example code? I'm new to spring boot & not able to figure out how should I implement it.

Comment: you can follow the below link to understand that 

https://blog.marcosbarbero.com/multiple-mongodb-connectors-in-spring-boot/

In the above link you go through steps till you create a configuration class "MultipleMongoConfig "  in that he defines two beans "primaryMongoTemplate" and "secondaryMongoTemplate" .  you can autowire them in your Repository class, the way you have done in the question you wrote. Just add @Qualifier("primaryMOngoTemplate")  and @Qualifier("secondaryMongoTemplate")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As rightly pointed out by @Lucia, below is how it can be done:

1. Have 2 different configuration placeholders

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.snk.repository", mongoTemplateRef = "mongoTemplateA")
public class MongoConfigA {
    // Configuration class for DB 1 access
}

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.snk.repository", mongoTemplateRef = "mongoTemplateB")
public class MongoConfigB {
    // Configuration class for DB 2 access
}
```

2. Get one class which will help in reading custom properties for mongo db properties in application.properties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "mongodb")
public class MultipleMongoProperties {

    private MongoProperties adb = new MongoProperties();
    private MongoProperties bdb = new MongoProperties();

    public MongoProperties getAdb() {
        return adb;
    }

    public MongoProperties getBdb() {
        return bdb;
    }
}
```

3. Add a configuration class to create mongoTemplates:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(MultipleMongoProperties.class)
public class MultipleMongoConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MultipleMongoProperties mongoProperties = new MultipleMongoProperties();

    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplateA")
    @Primary
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplateA() {
        return new MongoTemplate(aDbFactory(this.mongoProperties.getAdb()));
    }

    @Bean(name = "mongoTemplateB")
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplateB() {
        return new MongoTemplate(bDbFactory(this.mongoProperties.getBdb()));
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public MongoDbFactory aDbFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI(mongo.getUri()));
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory bDbFactory(final MongoProperties mongo) {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClientURI(mongo.getUri()));
    }
}
```

4. Add below decelerations to your service/repository:

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("mongoTemplateA")
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplateA;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("MongoTemplateB")
    private MongoTemplate MongoTemplateB;
```

4. Add below properties in your application.properties:

```
mongodb.adb.uri=mongodb://user:pass@myhost1:27017/adb
mongodb.bdb.uri=mongodb://user:pass@myhost2:27017/bdb
```

If you have mongo rplica set, URL can be set as:

```
mongodb.adb.uri=mongodb://user:pass@myhost1,myhost2,myhost13/adb?replicaSet=rsName
mongodb.bdb.uri=mongodb://user:pass@myhost1,myhost2,myhost13/bdb?replicaSet=rsName
```

Based on your logic, use either of the template.
Thought, there are few catches:

- Notice the @Primary annotation, one bean needs to be marked as primary. I haven't find any solution if no template is marked primary.
- If any of the mongo DB is down & application is started/restarted, application will not start/deploy. to avoid this, @Autowired needs to be changed to @Autowired(required = false).
- If any of the mongo DB is down & application is already running, it automatically uses 2nd mongo BD (which is not down). So, even if you want to use A DB, if it's down, requests are processed with B DB & vice-versa.

Comment: if i dont exclude the autoconfig, i will get Error of 
==== >   Parameter 2 of method gridFsTemplate in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:

Comment: Detailed article here https://stacktips.com/articles/how-to-connect-to-multiple-mongo-databases-in-springboot